# How can I use my Apple bluetooth keyboard for keyboard navigation on my iPad?

Tags: ipad, keyboard

I'm using an Apple bluetooth keyboard with my iPad. Even in Safari, arrow keys, Cmd-arrow for forward and back, Cmd-D for bookmark, etc do not work.  The only useful keyboard navigation is Return, Tab and Shift-Tab.

Are there perhaps some jailbroken apps that provide some sort of keyboard navigation shim?  Perhaps through GUI macros?

Comment: What version of iOS are you running?

Comment: I am running IOS 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sorry to say that I am unaware of any apps (jailbroken or otherwise) that add keyboard navigation to the iPad.

According to [GigaOm](http://gigaom.com/apple/ipad-keyboard-shortcuts/), the following shortcuts do work:

- <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> Copy selected text
- <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> Cut selected text
- <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> Paste
- <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> Undo
- <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> Redo
- <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd> Go to top of document
- <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd> Go to bottom of document
- <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>←</kbd> Go to start of line
- <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>→</kbd> Go to end of line
- <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⌫</kbd> Delete to end of line
- <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⌫</kbd> Delete previous word
- <kbd>F1</kbd> Make screen dimmer
- <kbd>F2</kbd> Make screen brighter
- <kbd>F7</kbd> Skip back one song
- <kbd>F8</kbd> Play or Pause Music
- <kbd>F9</kbd> Skip forward one song
- <kbd>F10</kbd> Mute Volume
- <kbd>F11</kbd> Decrease Volume
- <kbd>F12</kbd> Increase Volume
- <kbd>⏏</kbd> Show or hide onscreen keyboard

Comment: Sad.  I wonder if any Cydia or other jail broken apps provide this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice [article](http://decadentwaste.net/2011/03/navigate-using-a-bluetooth-keyboard-on-your-ios-device/) on enabling some keyboard features using VoiceOver. It is not perfect, especially due to the fact that it disables normal typing and scrolling with fingers, but it allows you to:

- Select items with keyboard (Left & Right buttons)
- Open Home Screen (Ctrl+Opt+H) and running applications (double that shortcut)
- Quick Search on current screen (Ctrl+Opt+I)
- and more.

I wish I could enable these shortcuts without switching on the whole VoiceOver feature.

Comment: That article changed my life. Fantastic!